# Strange survival mode only error

Tags: javascript, screeps

```
if(creep === Game.creeps["Worker0"])
{
    var sources = creep.pos.findClosest(Game.SOURCES);
    creep.moveTo(24,29);
    creep.harvest(sources);
    creep.transferEnergy(Game.creeps["Transport0"]);
}
if(creep === Game.creeps["Worker1"])
{
    var sources = creep.pos.findClosest(Game.SOURCES);
    creep.moveTo(25,29);
    creep.harvest(sources);
    creep.transferEnergy(Game.creeps["Transport0"]);
}
```

I get below error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined
    at RoomPosition.findClosest (/opt/engine/dist/game/rooms.js:843:23)
    at module.exports (harvester:7:30)
    at main:24:11
```

It is weird because it works just fine in simulation mode but not in survival.

Comment: Are you using `=` instead of `==` in your `if` conditions deliberately? I doubt it.

Comment: lol I keep doing that, still the same thing though. and it works perfectly fine in simulation mode why would it throw an error in survival?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Screeps API has been changed yesterday: [changelog](http://support.screeps.com/hc/en-us/articles/203154061-Changelog-2015-05-13).

You have to use `findClosest(FIND_SOURCES)` now instead of `findClosest(Game.SOURCES)`.

Comment: That fixed it. Why did it still work in simulation mode though?